# Unidirectional one to many, parent has composite key

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need to create a one to many mapping between a parent and child. Parent has an embedded id. I took this approach and I get:

**EDIT:**
The parent table contains 3 columns, which are foreign keys from 3 different Child tables.

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.Parent from com.Child has the
wrong number of column. should be 3
```

```
Parent {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ParentEmbeddedId id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "Child",
               joinColumns = {
                   @JoinColumn(name="childId2"),
                   @JoinColumn(name="childId3")
               },
               inverseJoinColumns={
                   @JoinColumn(name="childId1")
               })
    private Collection<Child> children;

}

ParentEmbeddedId {
    private long childId1;
    private long childId2;
    private long childId3;
}

Child {
    private long childId1;
}
```

**2nd approach:**

Using the below mapping also gives the same above exception:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "childId1")
private Collection<Child> children;
```

**3rd approach:**

```
@OneToMany
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="childId1", referencedColumnName="childId1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="childId2", referencedColumnName="childId2"),
    @JoinColumn(name="childId3", referencedColumnName="childId3"),
})
private Collection<Child> Children
```

This causes

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "Child2_"."childId3": invalid identifier;
```

Basically, the query generated by hibernate is trying to run query using "childId3" column that does not exist in "Child" table.

Comment: why inverseJoinColumns?

Comment: @chomnoue my approach 2 without the inverse column didn't work, so I tried the first approach

Comment: Why the embedded id at all? Does the parent always have 3 children? Doing a join on 3 columns is inefficient. If you post your table structure you want it will be easier to say what mapping you need.

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
 Child {
    private long childId1;
    private long childId2;
    private long childId3;
}
```